# Update item flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow, power-automate, choice-field

I would like to set up a flow so that when a choice column changes to a certain value, it triggers a flow to update a column on a different list.

I included destination ID column entry so that the flows knows which entry to update.

Could anyone direct/ advise on this flow set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample flow for your reference:

[image]

There are a couple of triggers and actions targeting on items or document you can choose based on your need.

Reference: [Microsoft SharePoint Connector in Power Automate.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Get changes to an item or file (properties only)” action in your Power Automate flow to track the column changes.

**Reference**: [Run a flow when a SharePoint column is modified](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/run-a-flow-when-a-sharepoint-column-is-modified)

**Other References**:

1. [Power Automate: Start a Flow from a column change](http://www.benprins.net/2020/09/01/power-automate-start-a-flow-from-a-column-change/)
2. [Flow when a SharePoint Column is updated](https://wonderlaura.com/2020/08/25/flow-when-a-sharepoint-column-is-updated/amp/)